# Pod Affinity in Skuber

Tags: scala, kubernetes

When creating Kubernetes Pods with [Skuber](https://github.com/doriordan/skuber), how do you define a Pod that has affinity with another Pod?

Eg:

```
val podASpec = Pod.Spec( ..., affinity = podB )
val podBSpec = Pod.Spec( ..., affinity = podA )
```

Answer (score 0):

First, decide on a [topologyKey](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/assign-pod-node/#inter-pod-affinity-and-anti-affinity) to use.  If you want affinity to work per distinct node, you can use `kubernetes.io/hostname`.

You can create a Skuber Pod Affinity like so:

```
import skuber.Pod.Affinity
import skuber.Pod.Affinity.{PodAffinity, PodAffinityTerm}
import skuber.LabelSelector.dsl._

val podAffinty = PodAffinity( List(PodAffinityTerm(
  Some(LabelSelector("myLabel" is "something")),
  List("my-namespace"),
  topologyKey
)))
val affinity = Some( Affinity(None, Some( podAffinty ) ) )
```

and pass in `affinity=affinity` when creating your `Pod.Spec`.